# tkinter label without a white box around

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a background image, but you can see the white box around the labels where the background image is not visible. how is it possible to display the background image in the background of the label?

Here is my code:

```
mainframe = Tk()
mainframe_weight = "500"
mainframe_height = "225"
mainframe.geometry(mainframe_weight + "x" + mainframe_height)
mainframe.resizable(0, 0)
headline = "arial 30 bold"

Login = Frame(mainframe, width=1000, height=800)
Startpage = Frame(mainframe)



def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


def login():
    raise_frame(Startpage)
    mainframe.geometry("1000x800")


for frame in (Login, Startpage):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

back = PhotoImage(file="images\loginbg.gif")
Label(Login, image=back).place(x=0, y=0)

Label(Login, text="Login", font=headline).place(x=195, y=5)
Label(Login, text="Benutzername", font="Arial 18 bold").place(x=20, y=75)
Label(Login, text="Passwort", font="Arial 18 bold").place(x=20, y=125)
Usernameentry = Entry(Login, font="Arial 16").place(x=200, y=80, height=25)
passwordentry = Entry(Login, font="Arial 16", show="*").place(x=200, y=130, height=25)
Button(Login, text="Login", command=login, font="Arial 16 bold").place(x=375, y=175)

Label(Startpage, text="second frame").pack()
Button(Startpage, text="to frame 1", command=lambda: raise_frame(Login)).pack()

Login.tkraise()
mainframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter does not support transparent background in `Label`.  You can use `Canvas` as the container, then using `create_image()` to show the background image, `create_text()` to replace those labels and `create_window()` to add those entries.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the background of the label transparent. 
Choose a color (in this example black ) and set the attribut of your tkinter that everything with the background black have a transparent background. Like this:

```
mainframe.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
```